# Sending an image in an intent to messenger api gets an error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to send an image (Uri using FIleProvider) to messenger whithin my app. My onClickListener works very fine but when arriving to the messenger layout, it says in a dialog that "Messenger couldn't handle this file". My image is in my drawable file in my android project.

This is how I'm creating my intent, image Uri and my intent :

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "messenger_blue.jpg");
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.guivers.app.guivers.fileprovider", f);
Log.e("Message", "Uri = "+uri);
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
sendIntent.setType("image/jpg");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

and here is my provider declaration in my manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.guivers.app.guivers.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
    </provider>
```

I think there is a problem when creating my File object or when creatin my Uri file but I don't know where...

EDIT : my built uri is : content://com.guivers.app.guivers.fileprovider/external_files/messenger_blue.jpg Anyone ? I really need some help !

Comment: Try `image/jpeg` instead of `image/jpg` and see if you get better results.

Comment: it doesn't work with image/jpeg...

Comment: Set `image/*` it worked for me.

Comment: It doesn't work with image/* either